Getting 404 not found from Traefik
I'm setting up Traefik as a reverse proxy to a bunch of docker services. Here's how I run Traefik:
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v3.0.4
    container_name: traefik
    command:
      # Set log level to debug
      - --log.level=DEBUG
      # Enable Docker provider
      - --providers.docker=true
      # Do not expose containers unless explicitly told so
      - --providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false
      # Enable File provider
      - --providers.file=true
      # Specify the self-signed key configuration
      - --providers.file.filename=/conf/tls.yml
      # Traefik will listen to incoming request on port 80 (HTTP)
      - --entryPoints.web.address=:80
      # Traefik will listen to incoming request on port 443 (HTTPS)
      - --entryPoints.websecure.address=:443
      # Redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.permanent=true
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./certs:/certs
      - ./conf:/conf
    networks:
      - proxy

networks:
  proxy:
    name: proxy

Once Traefik is up and running, I added my first web app and I was successfully able to open the app from my browser. I then added my second and third web apps but I'm getting 404 not found on both of them. Here's how I run one of them:
services:
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer-ce:2.20.2
    container_name: portainer
    restart: unless-stopped
    labels:
      # Explicitly tell Traefik to expose this container
      - traefik.enable=true
      # The domain the service will respond to
      - traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule=Host(`portainer.somedomain.lan`)
      # Allow request only from the predefined entry point named "websecure" (HTTPS on port 443)
      - traefik.http.routers.portainer.entrypoints=websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.portainer.tls=true
      # Specify which port Traefik should use for communicating to the service
      - traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.port=9000
    volumes:
      - portainer-data:/data
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - proxy

volumes:
  portainer-data:

networks:
  proxy:
    name: proxy
    external: true

When I perform a curl I get the following:
# HTTP
$ curl -ki portainer.somedomain.lan
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://portainer.somedomain.lan/
Date: Wed, 31 Jul 2024 15:27:45 GMT
Content-Length: 17

Moved Permanently

This is to be expected because of how I set up Traefik to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS as moved permanently. However when I perform a curl using https:
# HTTPS
$ curl -ki https://portainer.somedomain.lan
HTTP/2 404 
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
x-content-type-options: nosniff
content-length: 19
date: Wed, 31 Jul 2024 15:31:14 GMT

404 page not found


You should probably post a compose file of a running and non-running app. You changed the service name in the labels to be unique for each app? Enable and check Traefik debug log and Traefik access log in JSON format.

I have copied together both your traefik and portainer setup into a docker-compose file and ran it successfully. Your issue must lay somewhere else.
Did you run portainer beforehand and clicked on the setting "Force HTTPS only"?
In this case you would need to correct your traefik service to point to 9443.
I recommend you try the following regardless, just to see if the port 9000 is the issue:
- traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.port=9443
- traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.scheme=https

Alternatively, you might want to ditch your portainer-data volume and try with a clean state.
A different thing that you might walk into issues with is that you are referencing the network "proxy" inside your first docker compose file and defining it in the second. Starting or stopping those in wrong order will cause issues.
Create a static docker network to avoid this:
docker network create proxy

